# python error "list indices must be integers" , they ARE integers

Tags: python

I am having a problem. I have an array of 31 elements called colors. I also have another array with integer numbers that vary between 0 and 31, this is called c. I want to produce a new array where the values in c are now the corresponding values in colors.

I write:

> > newarray=colors[c]

but get the error message "list indices must be integers" but c is an array of integers.
I am new to python and have not got time to do the tutorials as I just need it for a specific plotting task. Could anyone give me a hand?

Thanks

Comment: the array called c has around 6000 elements all of integer values between 0 and 31.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain exactly what you are trying to do. Out of context, I don't understand why the list callec 'c' would have 6000 integer values in the range 0 to 31

Answer (score 19):

array of integers != integer

list indices must be integers - you've given a list of integers.

You probably want a list comprehension:

```
newarray = [ colors[i] for i in c ]
```

EDIT:

If you're still getting the same error then your assertion that `c` is a list of integers is incorrect.

Please try:

```
print type(c)
print type(c[0])
print type(colors)
print type(colors[0])
```

Then we can work out what types you have got. Also a [short but complete example](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html) would help, and probably teach you a lot about your problem.

EDIT2:

So if `c` is actually a list of string, you should probably have mentioned this, strings don't get automatically converted to integers, unlike some other scripting languages.

```
newarray = [ colors[int(i)] for i in c ]
```

EDIT3:

Here is some minimal code that demonstrates a couple of bug fixes:

```
x=["1\t2\t3","4\t5\t6","1\t2\t0","1\t2\t31"]
a=[y.split('\t')[0] for y in x]
b=[y.split('\t')[1] for y in x]
c=[y.split('\t')[2] for y in x]  # this line is probably the problem
colors=['#FFFF00']*32
newarray=[colors[int(i)] for i in c]
print newarray
```

a) `colors` needs to be 32 entries long.
 b) the elements from c (`i`) in the list comprehension need to be converted to integers (`int(i)`).

Comment: thank you for your post, however when I write the command  as above the same error message is returned.

Comment: I think it is because the elemants of array c are stored as strings. When I type : 

type(c[1])

I get the message "<type"str"> and so I guess I need to change them to type"int". I am having trouble doing this as I can't seem to change them all at once.

Comment: I guess we both wrote that at the same time. Colors is also string.

Comment: Sorry colors[0] is a string, both the arrays are lists.

Comment: Just post your complete code.  We can not guess what you are doing from these comments.

Comment: from pylab import*
f=open("transformdata.txt")
x=f.readlines()
a=[y.split('\t')[0] for y in x]
b=[y.split('\t')[1] for y in x]
c=[y.split('\t')[2] for y in x]
subplot(111,projection="hammer")
colors=['#FFFF00',etc-there are 31 colours here]
newarray=[colors [i] for i in c]
p=plot([a],[b],"o",mfc=color)
show()

Comment: It would probably be best if you edit your question with your code. Also I don't think the pylab stuff is relevant to your problem.

Comment: With a MatLab background it can be really confusing. Is there any reasons why in Python it is impossible to extract specific elements at some positions from a list just by giving an array containing the positions? like  sublist = list[array_of_indexes]

Answer (score 2):

This is your code: (from your comment)

```
from pylab import* 
f=open("transformdata.txt") 
x=f.readlines() 
a=[y.split('\t')[0] for y in x] 
b=[y.split('\t')[1] for y in x] 
c=[y.split('\t')[2] for y in x]  # this line is probably the problem
subplot(111,projection="hammer") 
colors=['#FFFF00']*31
newarray=[colors [i] for i in c] 
p=plot([a],[b],"o",mfc=color) show()
```

Without knowing exactly what your data is, or what you're trying to accomplish, I'd suggest trying this:

```
c=[int(y.split('\t')[2]) for y in x]
```

Comment: the data consists of coordinates a(range -180 to 180) and b(range -90 to 90) of supernovae. The c value describes a property of the SN that has been returned from some Matlab functions. I want to plot this data onto the hammer projection plot where the c value will be described by a colour gradient. ie when c=0 the colour will be yellow and when c=31 the colour will be blue and all other values are linearly scaled inbetween these colours.
I have followed your advise but after the plot line I get the message "sequence length is 6643; must be 3 or 4"

Comment: sorry I have just seen a mistake in what I have written, the last line should read:
p=plot([a],[b],"o",mfc=newarray):  I think that the problem is here, I don't think that it can plot each point(a,b) with the same element of newarray.

Comment: When giving error messages it would be nice to tell us which line was causing the problem.

Comment: the "sequence length is 6643; must be 3 or 4" comes up after the line that starts p=plot etc.

Comment: I think you've got the arguments for plot very wrong - mfc takes a single color - at least that's how I read the documentation http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot I suggest asking a new question as you've moved off the original question.

Comment: In your code, a, b, and c are all  lists of strings.  You need to convert them to some kind of numeric types if you want to use them as numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not support arbitrary list indexing. You can use single integer index like c[4] or slice like c[4:10]. [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/SciPy) library has richer indexing capabilities. Or just use list comprehensions as Douglas Leeder advices.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I know what you are after...

So you have your list of 31 colours. Say for argument it is a list of 31 strings like this...

```
colours = [ "Black", "DarkBlue", "DarkGreen", ... "White" ]
```

And 'c' is an array of numbers in the range 0 to 31, but in random order...

```
import random
c = [x for x in xrange(32)]
random.shuffle(c)
# 'c' now has numbers 0 to 31 in random order
# c = [ 2, 31, 0, ... 1]
```

And what you want to do is map the values in c as an index into the list of colors so that you end up with a list of colors in as indexed by c and in that order...

```
mapped = [color[idx] for idx in c]
# mapped has the colors in the same order as indexed by 'c'
# mapped = ["DarkGreen", "White", "Black", ... "DarkBlue"]
```

If that ain't what you want then you need to revise your question!

I think you've got a basic problem in that your list of colours should have 32 elements (colours) in it, not 31, if the list 'c' is a random shuffle of all numbers in the range 0 to 31 (that's 32 numbers, you see).

Comment: the c array has over 6000 elements with a range of 0-31.

Answer (score 0):

If the colors are also `integer`s or `float`s, there is a much easier fix using Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
newarray = np.array(colors)[c]
```